# Missing MySQL extension required to run WordPress on custom Linux server

Tags: linux, unix, php, mysql, webserver

I need to get WordPress up on running on a custom Red Hat Linux server, but am getting the following error when attempting to visit the WordPress install page:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which
>   is required by WordPress.

I checked the PHP settings using `phpinfo()` and see some sections on `PDO`, but do not see a block for just `mysql`.

[image: configure commmand in phpinfo()]

[image: pdo in phpinfo()]

[image: mysqlnd in phpinfo()]

**php.ini**

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"

; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules"
```

Extensions listed in /usr/lib64/php/modules:

- dbase.so
- mysqli.so
- mysql.so
- pdo_mysql.so
- pdo.so
- pdo_sqlite.so
- phpcups.so

What needs to be done in order to resolve this error message?

Comment: in my case I just rebooted the PC, all works now.

Answer (score 2):

You possibly need to install `php-mysql`:

```
yum install php-mysql
```

Comment: Is that a definitive solution or a good guess helpful comment?

Comment: its a good guess that I've seen fix this issue before.  Another option would be to setup the mysqli extension